# Issues with bash profile

Tags: .bash-profile

Can anyone see if there are any errors in this bash `.profile` line?

`export PS1="\[\033[38;5;206m\]\h:\W \u $ \[\033[0m\]"`

When I activate it, it shows in like this:

```
$ source .profile
\[\033[38;5;206m\]\h:\W \u $ \[\033[0m\]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Consider posting this in unix.stackexchange.com if you don't get a good answer here shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Make your sure `TERM` environment variable matches your actual terminal.  For example, if you are using xterm, do a `export TERM=xterm`.

Also make sure you are actually in `bash` and not `/bin/sh`.